# Create an index for this query Heroku says is my slowest

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, activerecord

Heroku says this is my slowest query. How would your migration look to create an index to speed this up?

It is ordered by created_at: :asc ... not sure how this will work into the index...

Here is the query from Heroku dashboard:

```
SELECT "line_movements"."game_moneyline_home"
FROM "line_movements"
WHERE "line_movements"."event_id" = $1
ORDER BY  "line_movements"."created_at" ASC
```

Speed this up with an index?

Comment: Is that reliable @userkhan

Answer (score 1):

You can index event_id offcource.
Then if you really want to speed up the query, use integer timestamp for created_at.
You can do something like

```
#add column created_at_int:integer to line_movements
#line_movement.rb
after_create :store_unix_time
def store_unix_time
  update_attributes created_at_int: created_at.to_i
end
#and get the time converted back by
def created_at_timestamp
  DateTime.parse(Time.at(created_at_int).to_s).in_time_zone
end
```

sql sort by integer is faster than sort by datetime.

Comment: Very interesting